# IPad: list item text not showing

Tags: html, ipad, css

I have a popup with 5-6 items. when opening it on desktop browser all looks fine but when opening it on IPad the last `<li>` text is not showing until i click it (looking at it with debug tools, i see the text is there, it's just not showing):

**Before Click**

[image]

**After click**

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="capbIpadPopup capbIpadPopupSingleSelect capbDateRangePopup capbThinScrollbars"
  data-bind="css: {capbCustomRange: $data.isCustomRange()}" style="display: block;">
  <span data-bind="attr:{'class': $data.triangleClass ? $data.triangleClass : 'capbTriangleRight'}"
    class="capbTriangleRight"></span>
  <header>
    <a href="#" class="capbBtn capbBtnBack ui-link" data-bind="click: $data.onCancelClick">Cancel</a> <a href="#"
      class="cabpDoneSelectDates capbBtn capbBtnSave ui-link" data-bind="click: $data.onDoneClick">Done</a>
    <h2 data-bind="text: $data.title">Date Range</h2>
  </header>
  <ul class="capbValues" data-bind="visible: !$data.isCustomRange()" style="">
    <!-- ko foreach: $data.item -->
    <li class="capbEllipsis"
      data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onDateSelected,attr: {'id': $data.time ? $data.time.getTime() : 'All'}, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parents[1].filterString == name || !$parents[1].filterString &amp;&amp; $index()==0}"
      id="All">All</li>

    <li class="capbEllipsis"
      data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onDateSelected,attr: {'id': $data.time ? $data.time.getTime() : 'All'}, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parents[1].filterString == name || !$parents[1].filterString &amp;&amp; $index()==0}"
      id="1383256800000">Current Month</li>

    <li class="capbEllipsis capbCheckIconDark"
      data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onDateSelected,attr: {'id': $data.time ? $data.time.getTime() : 'All'}, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parents[1].filterString == name || !$parents[1].filterString &amp;&amp; $index()==0}"
      id="1376476930850">Current Quarter</li>

    <li class="capbEllipsis"
      data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onDateSelected,attr: {'id': $data.time ? $data.time.getTime() : 'All'}, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parents[1].filterString == name || !$parents[1].filterString &amp;&amp; $index()==0}"
      id="1356991200000">Current Year</li>

    <li class="capbEllipsis"
      data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onDateSelected,attr: {'id': $data.time ? $data.time.getTime() : 'All'}, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parents[1].filterString == name || !$parents[1].filterString &amp;&amp; $index()==0}"
      id="1368528130850">Last 6 Months</li>

    <li class="capbEllipsis"
      data-bind="text: name, click: $parent.onDateSelected,attr: {'id': $data.time ? $data.time.getTime() : 'All'}, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parents[1].filterString == name || !$parents[1].filterString &amp;&amp; $index()==0}"
      id="1352893330850" style="display: list-item;">Last 12 Months</li>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <li class="capbCustomRangeSelect"
      data-bind="click: $data.onCustomRangeClick, css:{capbCheckIconDark: $parent.filterString &amp;&amp;$parent.filterString.indexOf('/')&gt;-1}"
      style="display: list-item;">Custom Range</li>
  </ul>

</div>
```